# Can't display the accordion collapse properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

The results of the accordion display are not responsive

I'm learning to make an accordion collapse.
I have added css for the accordion page that is being created.
I have successfully implemented Accordion Collapse, but the result is not responsive.

I make code like this

```css
.MaskGrid {
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-left: 24px;
  width: 327px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.Prefilled {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  width: 295px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.box {  
  padding: 1.25rem;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 327px;
  height: 317px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.address---street-name {
  width: 295px;
  height: 280px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.54;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #1f2d3d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <style type="text/css">
     [aria-expanded="false"] > .expanded, [aria-expanded="true"] > .collapsed {
      display: none;
     }
      </style>
</head>
    
    <body>
<div class="container">
     <div class="row" id="accordion">
      <!-- one -->
         <div class="MaskGrid">
             <div class="Prefilled card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menuone" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menuone">
               <div class="NameText">Menu One</div>
                        <span class="collapsed"><i><img src="https://i.ibb.co/QXC72Qr/sa-arrow-down.png" class="sa-arrow-down"></i></span> 
                        <span class="expanded"><i><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xzFDHvj/sa-arrow-up.png" class="sa-arrow-up"></i></span>    
             </div>
             <div id="menuone" class="collapse">
              <div class="card-body box">
         <div class="address---street-name">
               <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
         </div>
      <!-- two -->
         <div class="MaskGrid">
             <div class="Prefilled card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menutwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menutwo">
               <div class="NameText">Menu Two</div>
                        <span class="collapsed"><i><img src="https://i.ibb.co/QXC72Qr/sa-arrow-down.png" class="sa-arrow-down"></i></span> 
                        <span class="expanded"><i><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xzFDHvj/sa-arrow-up.png" class="sa-arrow-up"></i></span>         
             </div>
             <div id="menutwo" class="collapse">
              <div class="card-body box">
         <div class="address---street-name">
               <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

I want to make a accordion menu responsive display when i choose MenuOne or Menutwo

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a little bit modified your code to make it properly responsive.

Because of some bootstrap rules that you need to know like **.row** bootstrap class has a **display: flex;** and any flex div has child div so child div is also taking a **display: flex;**

So, if you did not add extra div in flex child so your div called **.MaskGrid** has taking a **display: flex;**

if your accordion data is not visible then after the flex sibling divs always take the same hight in any situations.

Like below screenshot:
[image]

Also, I have added viewport for responsive design if you have not added then please add.

**Modified Code given Below:**

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- added viewport for responsive design -->
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style type="text/css">
            [aria-expanded="false"] > .expanded, [aria-expanded="true"] > .collapsed {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="accordion">
                <div class="col-auto"> <!-- added extra parent div -->
                    <!-- one -->
                    <div class="MaskGrid">
                        <div class="Prefilled card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menuone" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menuone">
                            <div class="NameText">Menu One</div>
                            <span class="collapsed"><i><img src="https://i.ibb.co/QXC72Qr/sa-arrow-down.png" class="sa-arrow-down"></i></span>
                            <span class="expanded"><i><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xzFDHvj/sa-arrow-up.png" class="sa-arrow-up"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menuone" class="collapse">
                            <div class="card-body box">
                                <div class="address---street-name">
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- two -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">  <!-- added extra parent div -->
                    <div class="MaskGrid">
                        <div class="Prefilled card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menutwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menutwo">
                            <div class="NameText">Menu Two</div>
                            <span class="collapsed"><i><img src="https://i.ibb.co/QXC72Qr/sa-arrow-down.png" class="sa-arrow-down"></i></span>
                            <span class="expanded"><i><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xzFDHvj/sa-arrow-up.png" class="sa-arrow-up"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menutwo" class="collapse">
                            <div class="card-body box">
                                <div class="address---street-name">
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.MaskGrid {
margin-top: 24px;
margin-left: 24px;
width: 327px;
height: auto; /*change 80px to auto*/
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.Prefilled {
margin-top: 16px;
margin-left: 16px;
margin-right: 16px;
margin-bottom: 16px;
width: 295px;
height: 48px;
background-color: transparent;
}
.collapse.show .box { /*added .collapse.show*/
padding: 1.25rem;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
flex: 1 1 auto;
width: 327px;
height: 317px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.collapse.show .address---street-name { /*added .collapse.show*/
width: 295px;
height: 280px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-stretch: normal;
line-height: 1.54;
letter-spacing: normal;
color: #1f2d3d;
}
```

Please try this code and let me know if you have any question.

Comment: it's worked.
thanks for the information about using the child div on bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this accordion based on bootstrap 4 and jquery, it works responsive well :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
      <section id="faq">
          <div class="faq container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="heading col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                  <h1>FAQ</h1>
                <h2 class="accordion-header">Accordio Element 1</h2> 
                <div class="accordion-content"> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed id semper risus in hendrerit. Tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue lacus.</p> 
                </div> 
                <h2 class="accordion-header">Accordio Element 2</h2> 
                <div class="accordion-content"> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque.</p> 
                </div> 
                <h2 class="accordion-header">Accordio Element 3</h2> 
                <div class="accordion-content"> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et.</p> 
                </div> 
                <h2 class="accordion-header">Accordio Element 4</h2> 
                <div class="accordion-content"> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed. At auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend. A diam maecenas sed enim.</p>
                    <p>Arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam. At lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit. Magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis.</p> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed. Hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Nec dui nunc mattis enim.</p>
                </div> 
                <h2 class="accordion-header">Accordio Element 5</h2> 
                <div class="accordion-content"> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem.</p> 
                </div> 

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!-- scripts js -->
      <script>
          $('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

        //Set The Accordion Content Width
        var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
        $('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });

        //Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
        $('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');

        // The Accordion Effect
        $('.accordion-header').click(function () {
          if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
            $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
          }

          else {
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
          }
        });
      </script>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
#faq{
    padding: 50px 0;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-bottom-color: #e4e4e4 !important;
    border-bottom-style: solid !important;
}
.accordion-header {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin: 6px 0 0 0;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #666666;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.accordion-content {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-top: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
.active-header {
    background-color: #ccad52;
    color: black;
    transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.active-header:hover {
    background-color: #ccad52;
    color: black;
}
.inactive-header {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.inactive-header:hover {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.active-header:after {
    content: "\f107";
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #886708;
}
.inactive-header:after {
    content: "\f105";
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    animation: czAccArrowFX .4s forwards;
    color: #b79531;
}
```